# Ubuntu doesn't boot after apt-get upgrade (black screen)

Tags: upgrade, boot-failure, init

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Some time ago (2 weeks) I ran apt-get upgrade. When complete I turned off the computer. I was on vacation. When I returned I noticed that my computer will not boot. During normal startup displays a black screen and the upper left corner blinking "_" character.

I tried to run the recovery mode from GRUB. Instead, the console displays the following screen view:

http://smaller.dyn.pl/rescue_mode.jpg

...init: Failed to spawn friendly-recovery pre-start process: unable to execute: No such file or directory

When I started in normal mode, changing the parameter 'quiet splash' to 'nomodeset', I saw the following view:

http://smaller.dyn.pl/normal_mode.jpg

Please advice how can I fix this problem, I'm new to Linux. I have no idea what I could do. On various forums I found similar problems but no effective solution. Configuration of the new station will take me a long time due to the nature of my work.

I'm working on Ubuntu Desktop 11.10

BR,
smaller

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: Integrated Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 4500; This is Dell Optiplex 760 Small Form Factor